# Singular Covariance Matrix in Expectation Maximization

Tags: python, gmm, expectation-maximization

I was trying to code up an EM algorithm in python for clustering images of different types. My understanding of the EM algorithm is as follows:

[image: EM Algo]

Accordingly, I coded the same in python. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
from scipy import stats

# μ: mean vector ∈ R^(self.m x self.n)
# Σ: covariance matrix ∈ R^(self.m x self.n x self.n)
# π: probabilities of each component

class gmm:
    def __init__(self,n_components):
        self.m = n_components
        self.π = np.random.random((self.m,))
        self.x = None
        self.Σ = None
        self.μ = None
        self.r = None
        self.n = None # length of data

    @classmethod
    def N(cls, x, μ, Σ):
        #print(Σ)
        #print('\n')
        return stats.multivariate_normal(μ, Σ).pdf(x)
    
    def E_step(self):
        for i,x_i in enumerate(self.x):
            den = 0
            for c in range(self.m):
                #print(self.Σ[c].shape)
                #print(self.μ[c].shape)
                #sys.exit()
                den+= self.π[c]*gmm.N(x_i,self.μ[c],self.Σ[c])
            #print(f'{den=}')
            for c in range(self.m):
                num = self.π[c]*gmm.N(x_i,self.μ[c],self.Σ[c])
                self.r[i,c] = num/den
            print(f'{self.r}\n')

    def M_step(self):
        m_c = np.sum(self.r, axis = 0)
        self.π = m_c/self.m
        for c in range(self.m):
            s1 = 0
            s2 = 0
            for i in range(self.n):
                s1+= self.r[i,c]*self.x[i]
                s2+= self.r[i,c]*(self.x[i]-self.μ[c]).dot(self.x[i]-self.μ[c])
            self.μ[c] = s1/m_c[c]
            self.Σ[c] = s2/m_c[c]

    def fit(self,x, iterations = 10):
        self.x = x
        self.n = x.shape[0]
        self.r = np.empty((self.n, self.m))
        self.μ = np.random.random((self.m, self.n))
        Sigma = [np.random.random((self.n, self.n)) for i in range(self.m)]
        Sigma = [0.5*(s + s.T)+5*np.eye(s.shape[0]) for s in Sigma] # A symmetric diagonally dominant matrix is PD
        #print([np.linalg.det(s) for s in Sigma])
        self.Σ = np.asarray(Sigma)
        for i in range(iterations):
            self.E_step()
            self.M_step()
    
    def params():
        return self.π, self.μ, self.Σ

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_dim = 5   # No. of data dimensions
    data = [[]]*6
    data[0] = np.random.normal(0.5,2, size = (300,))
    data[1] = np.random.normal(3,2, size = (300,))
    data[2] = np.random.normal(-1, 0.1, size = (300,))
    data[3] = np.random.normal(2,3.14159, size = (300,))
    data[4] = np.random.normal(0,1, size = (300,))
    data[5] = np.random.normal(3.5,5, size = (300,))

    p = [0.1, 0.15, 0.22, 0.3, 0.2, 0.03]
    vals = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    combined = []
    for i in range(data_dim):
        choice = np.random.choice(vals, p = p)
        combined.append(np.random.choice(data[choice]))

    combined = np.array(combined)

    G = gmm(n_components = 6)
    G.fit(combined)
    pi, mu, sigma = G.params()
    print(pi)
    print(mu)
    print(sigma)
```

Now comes the problem. While running the code, the covariance matrix Σ becomes singular after some iterations. Specifically, all the entries of Sigma become the same all of a sudden in a particular iteration.

I have tried adding some random noise to Σ while this happens, but this seems to only delay the inevitable.
Any help/comments will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Please do not use literal Greek as variables. Whilst possible since Python 3 adopted unicode, it's considered bad practice, because it makes the code more difficult to run on other computers, as they might not have the relevant unicode. Instead, just call them `Sigma, mu, pi` etc (although `pi` usually means the number 3.1415....).

Comment: @Adriaan I get your point but this makes the code much nicer and easier to read and understand

Comment: Except πℼ are all different unicode characters. So its easier to read, and a terrible nightmare to maintain and use/code. Also, most peopole have not a keyboard to write those easily...

Comment: @AnderBiguri So, are you supporting me or are you against the use of Unicode characters?

Comment: I thought it was quite clear, sorry. Terribly bad idea to use them.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the covariance matrix from becoming singular, you could add an arbitrary value along the diagonal of the matrix, i.e.

```
val * np.identity(size)
```

as this ensures that the covariance matrix will remain positive definite, and have an inverse. For instance, **[sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture)** uses the default value `1e-6` for their regularization.

Comment: Thanks for the response... I forgot to mention I tried adding some positive values in the diagonal to make the cov matrix diagonally dominant, every time it becomes singular. However, the algorithm doesn't converge if I do that. More specifically, if I make Σ diagonally dominant , then it temporarily avoids the problem of Σ becoming sigular but in subsequent iterations Σ again becomes singular. So, basically this approach makes Σ and the entire algorithm oscillate about some _local_ singularity